# How to start working with c6820 camera module?

Tags: usb, drivers, camera

I have acquired C6820 cmos camera, but I do not know how to go about it without the drivers cd?

The manual indicates that the camera can operate by using usb cable too but the LED doesn't glow, which shows the camera board isn't working.

What is the probable solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB to serial cable, get the kit of the camera from http://www.electronics123.com/s.nl/it.A/id.2721/.f. It has the serial cable which connects to the camera, and then you use the serial to USB cable to connect it to the computer. The CD comes with the kit which has the software included.

Answer (score 0):

This camera uses the com port for communication the usb should only be used to upload.

Unfortuantly I do not know where do download the program C6820AP.exe from. But you will need this to communicate with the device.